# how to show image by product attribute value in magento additional product information on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, product-view

I need to show product image in product page on additional information tab.
I created a attribute name certification marks.
that attribute contain CE, CLASSE II, ENEC, F, IP20 these values.
on additional information page i want to show the logo of these certification marks.
Basically i want to konow that how to show images instead of product attribute value on product page page in additional tab in magento.

I add image of additional  details.
[image]

here you can see the attributes values is showing...here i want to show logo of these values...

### my logos

[image]

this is individuals logo..i want to show in additional information page in magento instead of attribute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create or replace with the below content and put it in **app\design\frontend\Your-Package\Your-theme\template\catalog\product\view\attributes.phtml**

Also make logo named as CE.png,CLASSE II.png, ENEC.png, F.png, IP20.png and place it in **skin\frontend\Your-Package\Your-theme\images**

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if ($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>
    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <?php if ($_data['code'] == "certification_mark"): ?>
                        <?php $values = explode(',', $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])); ?>
                        <td class="data">
                            <?php foreach ($values as $value): ?>
                                <div style="float:left;"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("certification_marks/" . trim($value) . ".jpg") ?>"></div>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($_data['code'] != "certification_mark" ): ?>
                        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It is working for me. Let me know once you tried it.

Comment: its work with little change  <?php if($_data['code'] != "attributeid"): ?>